# regex to remove html markup

Tags: regex, wordpress

I need to remove some html markup that occurs inside an `img` tag. This string occurs, with different numerals

`id="BLOGGER_PHOTO_ID_5324252539155647458"`

in hundreds of WordPress posts, and this regex (when used in the plugin Search RegEx http://urbangiraffe.com/plugins/search-regex/)

`id="BLOGGER_PHOTO_ID_"(.*?)""`

throws a *"Invalid regular expression: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash"* error.

The `(.*?)` is a function that the RegEx plugin uses to match all characters. I.e., this

`<a href="(.*?)">` used in the plugin matches all characters in the href link between the `<` and the `>`

What do I need to escape?

Comment: What do you need to remove? From the short string you provided, it appears that it would need to be written using single and double quotes: id="BLOGGER_PHOTO_ID_'(.*?)'" - is the (.*?) a php function inside the ID? If so, would need a PHP wrapper also

Comment: @ckaufman, good point, I didn't illuminate how the `(.*?)` works. I just tried the single quotes and I get the same error. This must be an issue with the particular kind of expressions used in the plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's lines, which remove lines such id="BLOGGER_PHOTO_ID_5324252539155647458" from variable $value

```
$pattern = '#id="BLOGGER_PHOTO_ID_[0-9]+"#'
$value = preg_replace($pattern, '', $value)
```

And every regular expresiion must be with delimiters - [here is more](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)

Comment: Thanks! Works great. I will be able to use this for other things.